# How to join three row of result from a join one to many to multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I have to get the three first results of a one to many join. 
For example

```
JOIN `company`.`Reason`
  ON ((`company`.`Reason`.`quality_id` = `company`.`Quality`.`id`)))
```

where Quality has a one to many relation to Reason.

And I need to show in a column REASON_1 the first result from Reason, in REASON_2 the second and REASON_3 the third.

At the moment, I show only one row of result this way :

```
  `company`.`Reason`.`status`                                                AS `Reason`
```

And I don't know how this works, how does it select one row, and which one ?
And how can I do the same, but only with 3 rows and with different column name ?

Quality

```
ID | a  | b
1  | a1 | b1 
2  | a2 | b2
```

Reason

```
ID | quality_id  | status
1  | quality_id_1 | status_1 
2  | quality_id_1 | status_2
2  | quality_id_2 | status_1
2  | quality_id_2 | status_3
```

So if I want to get Reasons of Quality of id 1 I would get

```
REASON_1 | REASON_2 | REASON_3
status_1 | status_2 | null
```

Comment: It might be better to include some more information about the structure of the data you are querying so we can help better.Have you tried doing a row number on the columns ordered by reason and returning the first three results?

Comment: What decides which row ends up in Reason_1, Reason_2, Reason_3 - do you have some kind of ordering column?

Comment: @Bridge Nothing, I only need to put the column "status" of the table Reason in Reason_1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an ordering within the reason table partitioned by the id from quality and then pivot this out on the columns from quality that you wish to return. In my code below i have done this using variables and a subquery in order to avoid having to making modifications to the base tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Quality (
  QualityID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Value VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(QualityID)
  );

 CREATE TABLE Reason (
  ReasonID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  QualityID INT,
  Status varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(ReasonID)
  );

  INSERT INTO Quality (Value) VALUES ('A1'),('A2');

  INSERT INTO Reason (QualityID, Status) VALUES (1,'Test1'),(1,'Test2'),(2,'Test3'),(2,'Test4'),(2,'Test5');

  SET @RC = 0;
SET @QC = 0;

SELECT
Q.Value,
MAX(IF(R.OrderNo = 1, R.Status, NULL)) AS Status1,
MAX(IF(R.OrderNo = 2, R.Status, NULL)) AS Status2,
MAX(IF(R.OrderNo = 3, R.Status, NULL)) AS Status3
FROM Quality Q
INNER JOIN (SELECT
@RC:=CASE
    WHEN @QC = QualityID THEN @RC + 1
    ELSE 1
END AS OrderNo,
@QC:=QualityID as QualityID,
Status
FROM Reason R)R ON R.QualityID = Q.QualityID
GROUP BY Q.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, but I don't use SQL Server, I use mysql, and I don't think there is "pivot" here :/

Comment: Your solution will need to be a lot less elegant then can you store an ordering for the Status in your reason table?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't, I don't have the permission de modify them.

Comment: I have modified the code so it should now work in mysql but the principles are the same. Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much to try helping me ! I tried to adapt it to my database stucture but I got the error that I cannot use variables within a sql view. Sorry for ommiting it in my post, I just putted a tag.

Comment: No you would need to run this as a stored procedure